# Nesting Bootstrap grids in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi everyone I am wondering what is the correct way to nest a bootstrap grids within rails.

Currently in my index view I have something like

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<div class="row">
  render @user
</div>
<% end %>
```

my user partial is something like this

```
   <div class="col-md-3">
    user.title
    </div>
```

If have 9 users the html would evluate to something like

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title1 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title2 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title3 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title4 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title5 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title6 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title7 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title8 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title9
     </div>
</div>
```

I however would like it to evaluate to something like this

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title1 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title2 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title3 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title4 
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row"
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title5 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title6 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title7 
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title8 
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row"
     <div class="col-md-3">
      title9 
     </div>
</div>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in_groups_of method: http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of

```
<% @users.in_groups_of(4, false) do |users| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% users.each do |user| %>
       <%= render @user %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Didn't know about ```in_groups_of``` . But that is super awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was given by jverban and is

```
<% @users.in_groups_of(4, false) do |users| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% users.each do |user| %>
       <%= render @user %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```